# Azure Cloud Service Slot Setting

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

I have a staging and a production slot on a Azure "Cloud Service (classic)".

My app polls a hangfire db for jobs. I don't want the staging instance to also pick up jobs. An "App Service" appears to have slot specific settings but there is no option in the portal for the "Cloud Service".

Is there a way to set slot specific settings for a Cloud Service in Azure?

Comment: There's a "Configuration" tab, depending on whether you've selected the Production or Staging slot.

Comment: But that doesn't allow me to create slot specific app settings

Comment: @Co-der Did you ever find a way of detecting this effectively?

Comment: @Kieron afraid not

Comment: @Co-der Thanks for getting back to me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to set slot specific settings for a Cloud Service in
>   Azure?

AFAIK, No. Other than the DNS name a staging slot is similar to production slot. The main purpose behind having staging and production slot is to quickly test the application in production like environment without actually deploying the code in production.

You could consume Azure Service Management API inside your Cloud Service code to decide whether the current code is running in production or staging environment and accordingly pick up the job.